# Returning table fro multiple select UNION put in an array

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I want to use filtered data from a sql script and use it to run in the upgrade in DB using the filtered list to upgrade.

1) I have a SQL file which is changing daily and it looks like the following:

```
select 
'OBJECT1' object_name, 
'PACKAGE BODY' object_type, 
'999999' target_vers, 
(Select statement which finds current version),
Decode (decode which comperes target version and current version) status 
from DUAL union
```

select 
(the same 5 columns)
..
...
..

It could reach 100+ selects

2) I want to use only the table entries which target version>current version (sometimes target version could be < current version)

3) The object name corresponds to .code directory where the corresponding sql, view, pks is found.

4) After the filtered step I want to run these sql file in db server (looks like it would need to be done in loop).

5) since I am new to cmd/batch not sure how to do this.

```
for /f  %%k in ('sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%SCRIPTPATH%\CHECK_CODE.sql') do (
set theValue=%%k
)
```

The code above runs the sql file mentioned above,

```
spool new.txt 
select ...... 
spool off 
/ 
exit
```

This returns the below txt file

```
OBJECT_NAME                 OBJECT_TYPE  TARGE                                  
--------------------------- ------------ -----                                  
INSTALLED_VERS                                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STATUS                                                                          
-------------------------                                                       
OBJECT_NAME              PACKAGE BODY 72021                                  
72021                                                                           
--- INSTALLED ---
```

Now I would want to do a loop only through the needed objects to update the DB.

```
for /f  %%a in ('List of entries which need upgrade') 
do (
sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%%a.[object_name].[object extension]
)
```

The Question is how can I get the filtered data from the first SQL script into an array in CMD which would then use these to run the SQL files (which are identicall to object_name)

Comment: Please edit your question and fix your formatting, I do not mind helping but there is alot to format.

Comment: Apologizes, I thought it would recognize it automatically :)

Comment: I doubt it is necessary to use a batch file for the filtering; could this not be done by updating the SQL query?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. If I would get the ready query already in then I would do as:

for /f  %%k in ('sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%SCRIPTPATH%\CHECK_CODE.sql') do (
set theValue=%%k
)

Though the given query will always be in form as select.... Changing this would require more work to be done.

Thus I want to know if there is a possibility to run in these results, then use the output in an array, from which I then want to filter out only the ones needed for upgrade....

Comment: Actually, aschipfl you have a very good point there, I could add 'AND BLa_BLA='NEEDS_UPGRADE'' in the file, thus the filtering would be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something like:

```
DEL UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

set SCRIPTPATH=%CD%
set BAKNAME=LGH_670
set SCHEMAPATH=X:\HF\QA\Builds\Build Area\LGH\Linedata Global Hedge 6.7.0\QA1\LGH\Oracle_Objects
set LOGIN=LGH_670
set APPSERVER=LN1QAAPP11
set DBSERVER=LN1QADB11_FM.WORLD
set num=0

ECHO ********************************* Loging is starting before services being stopped *************************************** >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

ECHO *** Stopping services >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

NET STOP %LOGIN% >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

ECHO *** Checking V_MQ >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

for /f  %%k in ('sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%SCRIPTPATH%\help_scripts\MESSEGE_QUEUE.sql') do (set theValue=%%k)    

cat V_MQ.txt | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' >> V_MQ_2.txt

find /c "norowsselected" V_MQ_2.txt
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto queufull
    goto queueempty
    :queueempty

del V_MQ_2.txt
del V_MQ.txt

for /f  %%k in ('sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%SCRIPTPATH%\help_scripts\USER_OBJECTS.sql') do (set theValue=%%k)


cat USER_OBJECTS.txt | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' >> USER_OBJECTS_2.txt

find /c "norowsselected" USER_OBJECTS_2.txt
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto queufull
    goto validobjects
    :validobjects

del USER_OBJECTS_2.txt
del USER_OBJECTS.txt


ECHO ***Coppying data from "%SCHEMAPATH%" >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

xcopy /s "%SCHEMAPATH%\*.*" *.* /Y

ECHO *** Creating Upgrade scripts and cleaning up the folder >> UPGRADE_LOG.TXT

call %SCRIPTPATH%\replace_string.bat V_WHAT V_WHAT_BAK CHECK_CODE.sql

REM ################### Here CHECK_CODE would be checked ##############################

echo select Object_name, object_type from ( > CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql >> CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql.new > CHECK_CODE.sql

del CHECK_CODE.sql.new

echo spool CODE_CHECK.txt > CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql >>CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql.new > CHECK_CODE.sql

del CHECK_CODE.sql.new


echo set headsep off > CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql >>CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql.new > CHECK_CODE.sql

del CHECK_CODE.sql.new

echo set pagesize 0 > CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql >>CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql.new > CHECK_CODE.sql

del CHECK_CODE.sql.new


echo create table V_WHAT_BAK as select * from V_WHAT; > CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql >>CHECK_CODE.sql.new
type CHECK_CODE.sql.new > CHECK_CODE.sql

del CHECK_CODE.sql.new

REM Adding last lines in the system

echo  ) where status='### NEEDS UPGRADE ###'; >> CHECK_CODE.sql
echo spool off >> CHECK_CODE.sql
echo DROP TABLE v_what_bak; >> CHECK_CODE.sql
echo / >> CHECK_CODE.sql
echo exit >> CHECK_CODE.sql

REM Here We need to run in the script for alternative check.

for /f  %%k in ('sqlplus -s %LOGIN%/%LOGIN%@%DBSERVER% @%SCRIPTPATH%\CHECK_CODE.sql') do (set theValue=%%k)
```